# Linq - check condition in where clause if field can be null

Tags: c#, linq

I have question - how to check condition in where clause even when item has no reference?

Most basic way - I am checking field from my Class, which can be null. When I just check it in that way it will return Null Reference Exception

```
 var soldOutProducts = from p in list 
            where p.destinataire.StartsWith("D") 
            select p;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: adding where clause only when a value is not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787794/linq-adding-where-clause-only-when-a-value-is-not-null)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

can you do

```
var soldOutProducts = from p in list
                      where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.destinataire) and
                            p.destinataire.StartsWith("D")
                      select p;
```

Comment: Why bother using `IsNullOrEmpty` rather than a simple `null` test? An empty string doesn't start with `D`, so it should give the same results, and it's a more general approach that works for all nullable types, not just string.

Comment: @JonSkeet Probably a force of habit. Or strict code analysis rules, I think the default VS CA settings tell you to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead of `s == null` :D

Answer (score 7):

Just check for null first, just as you would if you were writing normal C# code in a loop.

```
where p.destinataire != null && p.destinataire.StartsWith("D")
```

If `p` itself can be null (i.e. your list can contain null elements) then you need to check for that too:

```
where p != null && p.destinataire != null && p.destinataire.StartsWith("D")
```

Note that if your query expression is *just* doing filtering, you might want to use dot notation instead:

```
var soldOutProducts = list.Where(p => p.destinataire != null && 
                                      p.destinataire.StartsWith("D"));
```

Query expressions are really beneficial when the query gets complicated - particularly with joins and grouping.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var soldOutProducts = from p in list 
            where p.destinataire != null && p.destinataire.StartsWith("D") 
            select p;
```